# Show colorscale even if no trace is selected in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I have a plotly plot, with 2 traces where the markes ale color-coded. To show the colorscale I added showscale=True for each trace (both traces are normed).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [50.941357, 50.932171],
                    'lon': [6.957768, 6.964412],
                    'value': [0.5, 0.75]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [50.938571, 51.038203],
                    'lon': [6.961860, 7.001457],
                    'value': [0.25, 0.99]})


def get_trace(df, trace_name):
    trace = go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df['lat'],
        lon=df['lon'],
        mode='markers',
        name=trace_name,
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            color=df['value'],
            colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [0.5, 'yellow'], [1.0, 'red']],
            size=40,
            cmin=0,
            cmax=1,
            showscale=True
        ),
    )
    return trace


fig = go.Figure([get_trace(df1, 'trace 1'), get_trace(df2, 'trace 2')])

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                  mapbox={'center': go.layout.mapbox.Center(lat=50.970990, lon=6.984498), 'zoom': 11},
                  showlegend=True,
                  legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1}
                  )

fig.show()
```

This yields to the following map:

[examplePlot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYyWB.png)

If I deselect both traces in the legend, then (of course) the colourscale is also not visible:

[examplePlot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNxv1.png)

How can I show the colorscale no matter if a trace is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.
I addes an pseudo-empty trace and hided it in the legend.

```
empty_trace = go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=[0.0],
    lon=[0.0],
    mode='markers',
    name='empty',
    showlegend=False,
    marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
        colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [0.5, 'yellow'], [1.0, 'red']],
        size=0,
        cmin=0,
        cmax=1,
        showscale=True
    ),
)
```

For the other traces I deleted `showscale=True`